# How to reduce number of output files in Apache Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, emr

Does anyone know of a tool that can "crunch" the output files of Apache Hadoop into fewer files or one file. Currently I am downloading all the files to a local machine and the concatenate them in one file. So does anyone know of an API or a tool that does the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Limiting the number of output files means you want to limit the number of reducers. You could do that with the help of `mapred.reduce.tasks` property from the Hive shell. Example :

```
hive>  set mapred.reduce.tasks = 5;
```

But it might affect the performance of your query. Alternatively, you could use `getmerge` command from the HDFS shell once you are done with your query. This command takes a source directory and a destination file as input and concatenates files in src into the destination local file.

Usage :

```
bin/hadoop fs -getmerge <src> <localdst>
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

See https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-Multiple-Small-Files/td-p/204038

```
set hive.merge.mapfiles=true;     -- Merge small files at the end of a map-only job.
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;  -- Merge small files at the end of a map-reduce job.

set hive.merge.size.per.task=???; -- Size (bytes) of merged files at the end of the job.

set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=??? -- File size (bytes) threshold
-- When the average output file size of a job is less than this number, 
-- Hive will start an additional map-reduce job to merge the output files 
-- into bigger files. This is only done for map-only jobs if hive.merge.mapfiles 
-- is true, and for map-reduce jobs if hive.merge.mapredfiles is true.
```